# How to update the state after a data update through an API request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small problem. I have this fetch data in one component which is working perfectly:

```js
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://api/products")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setItem(data))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Then I have this POST in a different component:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await fetch("https://api/products", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { admin: "true", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
```

How can I get the new data of the first component after using POST without reloading the web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be able to append that new data, `body` inside `item` array, means you need to call this `setItem(prev => [...prev, body])` in your `try-catch`, something like:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await fetch("https://api/products", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { admin: "true", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      setItem(prev => [...prev, body]); // here you add the new data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
```

Now how you would access this `setItem` function? Well if the component that's making the POST request is a child of the component where you have this line `const [item, setItem] = useState([])`, you could pass `setItem` as a `props`.

If it's not the case, either you move this `const [item, setItem] = useState([])` inside a component that's parent of all those components and pass down what you need as `props` or use a state management solution like the [`context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: ahh ok I undertand, I think I will use context API because I need to use that same data of the fetch in another component. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You must call the function again when response is true.
I mean your function when getting data.

Comment: or else try to push data on your current state